# No key/value pairs being saved in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsmutabledictionary

When my app starts, it loops through adding values of random numbers with keys of co-ordinates on a grid to a dictionary. Here is a bit of the code:

```
[grid setObject:v forKey:k];
```

K is a string in form "xy" where x and y are single digit integers and V is an NSNumber. Both of these are logged to the console before adding so I know these aren't the problem. However, despite this code running 49 times (for a 7 x 7 grid) the dictionary is empty at the end.

grid is defined in my header file with:

```
NSMutableDictionary *grid;
```

And then I initialised it when the app loads (but I don't know if I have to do this) using the code:

```
grid = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] retain];
```

This is really confusing me because I have only just started learning Objective-C and I have come from the far more forgiving universe of C# and Python.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Just to be sure, where (in what function/method) did you "initialize it when the app loads"?

Comment: You don't need to retain the result of `alloc` and `init`. Because you allocked it, you already own it; with your current code, you own it twice. Review the memory management rules: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C, sending a message to `nil` (a `null` reference in the C# world), is both legal and common. The result is `nil`, and so will often pass silently. Once you wrap your head around this, it's a very useful tool that makes code a lot cleaner (no checks for null, etc.). So, put a breakpoint at the line where you add an entry to the dictionary. To do so, click in the gutter next to the line in Xcode. Run your application with Breakpoints turned on. When the debugger stops at that line, you can hover the mouse over `grid`. I suspect you'll see that it's `nil` (`0x0`). You can also open the run console and type `po grid` to print gdb's description of `grid`. Again, I think you'll find that it's nil.

Without seeing more code, it will be impossible to help you track down why `grid` is `nil`.

On a side note, you don't need the extra `-retain` following `alloc/init`. Read the Memory [Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). It will be your friend.

Comment: Thank you for this help. I found the issue. The code to fill grid was being called before I had set grid in appDidFinishLaunching: Thanks! A stupid mistake, but I understand more about Objective-C because of it so I guess it is a good thing.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help. Good luck with Objective-C.